# Seeding file uploads with CarrierWave, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, carrierwave, seed

I'm trying to seed a database in Rails 3 with images using CarrierWave, however nothing I try seems to work short of having to upload them all by hand.

```
pi = ProductImage.new(:product => product)
pi.image = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'test.jpg'))
pi.store_image! # tried with and without this
product.product_images << pi
product.save!
```

Anybody know how to seed using CarrierWave at all?

Comment: Sorry if I'm way off the mark, but is 'pi' a reserved word at all?

Comment: Nope, pi in ruby is represented as a constant, which is case sensitive as `PI`. Interesting thought nonetheless. ;]

Comment: Thats `Math::PI` by the way. ;]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Turns out the documentation for CarrierWave is slightly wrong. There is a more up to date piece of code [in the README at the GitHub repository for the project](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

In a nutshell, though:

```
pi = ProductImage.create!(:product => product)
pi.image.store!(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'test.jpg')))
product.product_images << pi
product.save!
```

Comment: It is also possible to do this in a single line if desired: 
`ProductImage.create!(:product => product, image: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'test.jpg')))`

Comment: It is also possible to do the entire action in one line `product.product_images.create!(image: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'test.jpg')))`

Answer (score 11):

So long as your uploader is mounted to your model, using the mount_uploader method, you can seed your models with carrierwave using the relevant open method. This would be a more concise way of achieving the same thing. In my case I'm seeding from a URL:

```
Game.create([
{
  :title => "Title",
  :uuid_old => "1e5e5822-28a1-11e0-91fa-0800200c9a66", 
  :link_href => "link_href", 
  :icon => open("http://feed.namespace.com/icon/lcgol.png"),
  :updated_at => "2011-01-25 16:38:46", 
  :platforms => Platform.where("name = 'iPhone'"), 
  :summary => "Blah, blah, blah...", 
  :feed_position => 0, 
  :languages => Language.where("code = 'de'"), 
  :tags => Tag.where(:name => ['LCGOL', 'TR', 'action'])
},
{...
```

Comment: Instead of using `open`, `remote_[attribut name]_url`can be supplied instead.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @joseph jaber's comment this worked a treat for me:

The code below shoud be in `seeds.rb`

```
20.times do
        User.create!(
            name: "John Smith",
            email: "john@gmail.com",
            remote_avatar_url: (Faker::Avatar.image)
        )
    end
```

This will create 20 users and give each one a different avatar image.

I have used the faker gem to generate the data but all `Faker::Avatar.image` does is return a standard url, so you could use any url of your choice.

The above example assumes that the User models attribute where you store you images is called `avatar`

If the attribute was called image you would write like this:

`remote_image_url: (Faker::Avatar.image)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example script I incorporated into a seed.rb file for one of my projects.
I'm sure it can be improved but it provides a good working example.

All the assets I'm pulling are stored within the app/assets/images and they have names matching the names of my Info objects (after I replace spaces with underscores and downcase the names).

Yes it does sound inefficient, but apart from putting those assets on an FTP somehwhere, it's the best solution I found for my remote server to be able to upload the files straight to S3 using Carrierwave and Fog.

My Info model has a `has_one` association to a Gallery model, which has a `has_many` association to a Photo model. The Carrierwave uploader is mounted on the 'file' (string) column of that model.

```
Info.all.each do |info|              
  info_name = info.name.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
  directory = File.join(Rails.root, "app/assets/images/infos/stock/#{info_name}")

  # making sure the directory for this service exists
  if File.directory?(directory)
    gallery = info.create_gallery

    Dir.foreach(directory) do |item|
      next if item == '.' or item == '..'
      # do work on real items
      image = Photo.create!(gallery_id: gallery.id)
      image.file.store!(File.open(File.join(directory, item)))
      gallery.photos << image
    end

    info.save!

  end
end
```

This works flawlessly for me, but ideally I wouldn't have to package the files that I'm uploading to S3 within the assets folder. I'm more than open to suggestions & improvements.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the documentation: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file

```
restaurant = Restaurant.create!(name: "McDonald's")
restaurant.logo = Rails.root.join("db/images/mcdonalds_logo.png").open
restaurant.save!
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution for me was:

1. Comment-out the mount_uploader line in the model
2. Seed the data
3. Uncomment the line in the model

Comment: As soon as you  uncomment the model uploader, the file attr of the mounted field is nil