# Rake db:seed complaining about form not being multipart encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a seeds.rb file:

```
activity1 = Activity.create! :name => 'Football', :icon => File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/activity_icons/football.png")
```

But when I run **rake db:seed**, the process fails and I get an error message:

```
You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.

If this is a file upload, please check that your upload form is multipart encoded.
```

Well, manual icon uploads do work because my form **is** multipart encoded so I'm guessing that rake is using it's own form running seeds.rb.

What do I have to do to make this work?  Besides manually adding the icons each time I recreate my db

Comment: What plugin/gem are you using for your file attachments? paperclip/attachment_fu?

Comment: I'm using CarrierWave (master branch from github) and Fog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this thanks to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910162/seeding-file-uploads-with-carrierwave-rails-3)

Just had to fix the code in my seeds file a bit.  The following works:

```
activity = Activity.create! :name => 'Football', :icon => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/public/images/activity_icons/soccer.png'))
```