# How can I access files from a rake task on heroku?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to seed data in a Rails app, particularly one using carrierwave. I am using a combination of 2 nice solutions found here on stackoverflow!

[rake task + yml files for seeding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64822/1449799)

[seeding carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3913323/1449799)

I have the following:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "This loads the development data."
  task :seed => :environment do
    require 'active_record/fixtures'
    Dir.glob(RAILS_ROOT + '/db/fixtures/*.yml').each do |file|
      base_name = File.basename(file, '.*')
      puts "Loading #{base_name}..."
      ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures('db/fixtures', base_name)
    end
    #add in the image file for the default data
    for item in Item.find(:all)
      item.filename.store!(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "app/assets/images/objects/" + item.name.gsub(/ /,'').downcase + ".svg")))
      item.save!
    end
  end

  desc "This drops the db, builds the db, and seeds the data."
  task :reseed => [:environment, 'db:reset', 'db:seed']
end
```

However on heroku, I keep getting errors about the path such as

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - app/assets/images/objects/house.svg
```

I have tried several versions of the line:

```
item.filename.store!(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "app/assets/images/objects/" + item.name.gsub(/ /,'').downcase + ".svg")))
```

where I basically changed out using File.join and just concatenation and also trying to use the RAILS_ROOT which seemed to work ok above, but I always seem to get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you creating any files in `app/assets/images/objects/` or otherwise putting data there? Does that directory exist in your git repo? You can check if the directory exists on heroku by running `heroku run ls app/assets/images/objects/` from the command line.

All apps running on heroku use an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but **no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno** and **any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted**.

What this means is that unless you have files in a directory called `app/assets/images/objects/` inside your git repository or you're creating those files programatically after your program is deployed, there may not actually be any such files or a directory by that name.

Comment: I do indeed have files at that location... It turns out i didn't, locally I renamed many files such as House.svg to house.svg, but i didn't do it in a git happy way, so heroku was unaware of these changes, and my script failed. THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!