# Override Rails Uploader to seed database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a CarrierWave rails uploader. I want to seed the database with fake users so I'm trying to add the images in with the same seed file. The images are in a common storage, so if I can just get the avatar strings in the database they'll work. When it saves the users though the image's aren't sticking.

```
# db/seeds.rb
user1 = User.create :email => "test1@test.com", :password => "testing", :name => "Bob Dylan", :avatar => "v1357014344/bdylan.jpg"
user1.save

# IRB
User.first
=> #<User id: 1, email: "test1@test.com", name: "Bob Dylan", avatar: nil> 

> a = User.first
> a.avatar = "v1357014344/bdylan.jpg"
> a.save
 (10.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true 
> a
=> #<User id: 1, email: "test1@test.com", name: "Bob Dylan", avatar: nil>
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to insert the data in the following way.

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'test.jpg'))
```

So the entire user create would look like

```
User.create :email => "test1@test.com", :password => "testing", :name => "Bob Dylan", :avatar => open("v1357014344/bdylan.jpg")
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910162/seeding-file-uploads-with-carrierwave-rails-3)

Answer (score 3):

Besides using `open()` as [Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156775/nishant) suggestions, you can also specify `remote_avatar_url` to manually set the remote URL.

```
User.create :email => "test1@test.com", :password => "testing", :name => "Bob Dylan", :remote_avatar_url => "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Joan_Baez_Bob_Dylan_crop.jpg"
```

Thanks to [JosephJaber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173986/josephjaber) for suggesting this in [Seeding file uploads with CarrierWave, Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910162/seeding-file-uploads-with-carrierwave-rails-3#comment17874023_12895838)

I used this approach to populate some video URLs for CarrierWave Uploader in my seeds.rb

Answer (score 1):

To update the database directly and skip out on CarrierWave:

```
model[:attribute] = 'url.jpg'
model.save
```