# Rails 4 - Seed images from hard drive with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to seed images with carrierwave. After looking at some questions, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108154/override-rails-uploader-to-seed-database) one, I have tried:

```
c1 = Category.create(
  name: "About Us",
  page_title: "12 Years of Tradition",
  page_description: "long description here",
  page_content: "a lot of content here",
  link_to_subcategory: "Meet the Robinson's",
  banner_image: open("RF_web_about_us_1.jpg"),
  main_image: open("RF_web_about_us_2.jpg"),
  home_page_content: "content here"
  )
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I run rake db:seed

```
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - RF_web_about_us_1.jpg
```

The image (RF_web_about_us_1.jpg) is stored in app/assets/images. Any help at all with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You probably have to specify the full path, like `banner_image: File.open(Rails.root + "assets/images/RF_web_about_us_1.jpg")`

Comment: @Sharagoz Nope, that didn't work. I get the same error except with the full path specified

Comment: I forgot the `app` folder in the example. add it to the start of the path. You can also open the console and experiment with `File.open` command until it no longer returns the error.

Comment: @Sharagoz Thanks so much! That's working perfectly now :) If you put it into an answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the full path to the image:

File.open(Rails.root + "app/assets/images/RF_web_about_us_1.jpg")

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this:

```
Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/RF_web_about_us_1.jpg").open
```

So your create statement will look like:

```
c1 = Category.create(
  name: "About Us",
  page_title: "12 Years of Tradition",
  page_description: "long description here",
  page_content: "a lot of content here",
  link_to_subcategory: "Meet the Robinson's",
  banner_image: Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/RF_web_about_us_1.jpg").open,
  main_image: Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/RF_web_about_us_2.jpg").open,
  home_page_content: "content here"
)
```

Reference: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file